# how to calculate the space of a file in memorycache?

Tags: c#, memorycache

my goal is to calculate how much space a file occupies in memorycache , 
to do this I made a method that loads thousands of objects into memory and calculates the difference of some values ​​between before loading the objects and after , 
this before file addition:

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long memoriaNonPaginata = p.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64;
long memoriaPaginata = p.PagedMemorySize64;
long memoriaDiSistema = p.PagedSystemMemorySize64;           
long ramIniziale = memoriaNonPaginata + memoriaPaginata + memoriaDiSistema;
```

I add files:

```
while (counter < numeroOggettiInCache)
{
    string k = counter.ToString();
    data = data + k.Substring(0,1);
    int position = r.Next(0, 28000);
    data = data.Remove(position, 1);                
    _cache.CreateEntry("cucu" + counter.ToString());
    _cache.Set("cucu" + counter.ToString(), data, opt);                
    counter++;
}
```

I'm going to calculate the values ​​later:

```
Process p1 = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long memoriaNonPaginataPost = p1.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64;
long memoriaPaginataPost = p1.PagedMemorySize64;
long memoriaDiSistemaPost = p1.PagedSystemMemorySize64;
long ramFinale = memoriaNonPaginataPost + memoriaPaginataPost + memoriaDiSistemaPost;
```

I ask if the properties I used (NonpagedSystemMemorySize64,PagedMemorySize64,PagedSystemMemorySize64) are correct and sufficient to calculate how much space the cached files use, thank you,regards

Comment: I have used memorycache using .net

Comment: I solved it, I found a property that contains the amount of physical memory which is fine compared to what I was looking for